# enlarging the figure in the pop-out window in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, figure

How to enlarge a figure inside the pop-out window? I use the following code to generate my figure:

```
self._fig = plt.figure()
#self._fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2,1)) # tried this, didn't work, only change the size of the pop-out window, but now the figure itself
ax1 = self._fig.add_subplot(211,projection='3d')

# some code for plotting the lines and drawing the spherical surfaces, which is not shown here

ax1.set_xlim(-6,6)
ax1.set_ylim(-6,6)
ax1.set_zlim(-15,15)
ax1.set_aspect(2.5, 'box') # the axis limit and aspect limit is chosen so that the whole figure has the same scale in all directions
#ax1.view_init(elev=90, azim=0)

ax1.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax1.set_zlabel('Z-axis')  
ax1.grid(True)
```

You can see that there is lot of unused space in the pop-out window, and the figure looks really small. I want to maximize the size of the figure so that it fills the whole pop-out window. Now even if I manually enlarge the pop-out window, the figure still looks the same.

I tried varying the axis limits, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried setting the 
figsize in the first line, but it only changes the size of the pop-out window, but the figure itself.

Another problem is that I want to change the 'camera-view' of the figure so that the z-axis (the lone axis) is horizontal. Again, I tried a range of different values in ax.view_init, but I can't get the view I want. I only allows me rotate around the z-axis, while what I need to do is to rotate around x or y-axis by 90deg.

[image]

Comment: what version of mpl?  Do you mean to be creating a 2x1 grid of axes?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you meant. What is mpl? And what did you mean by 2x1 grid of axes? All I want is to make this 3d figure appear larger in the pop-out window, instead of leaving so many empty space as shown in the attached image.

Comment: `ax1 = self._fig.add_subplot(211,projection='3d') ` that adds an axes to the figure as the first axes of a 2x1 grid., try `self._fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d') `.

Comment: it works. thank you so much! but what about rotating the whole figure by 90deg? Now it does fill the majority of the pop-out window, but since the figure is longer along the z-axis, it would be much better to have the z-axis aligned along the horizontal direction. I tried many different values in the ax.view_init but none of them gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `plt.tight_layout()`

before you call `plt.show()`